# apk signed with a different certificate problem

Tags: java, android, keystore, sha1, app-inventor

My original application was created in Android Studio and I have updated it by appybuilder.

When I uploaded to Play Google, they said there is a problem with keystore, 
the new apk is signed with a different certificate to my previous one. When I tried to import the old key file to appybuilder the extension was not the same (jks in android studio, keystore with appybuilder).

How can I export the older key file .jks to a .keystore file?

[image]

```
[ SHA1: 49:13:64:3F:A0:BE:36:5E:C4:16:6B:3F:25:33:D5:3C:5F:4B:72:8F ]
```

Comment: `jks` is the abbreviation of "Java Keystore File". Appybuilder explicitly mentions this format. Therefore if the file is really a JKS file this is not the problem. You can use [KeyStoreExplorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) to load it and check what file format it really is.

Comment: wen i was working with android studio i have save it correctly, i opened it by keystoreexplorer it is ok, but appybuilder accept only .keystore file

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the right keystore file? Check the fingerprints shown in Keystore explorer for the certificate(s).

Comment: i opened the file, all details are correct, md5 sha1...